# Mat Table Not Sorting After View Change

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have an ngIf that changes the view on click on the products screen. The starting view is the data in a mat table, but once you click the add product button and [cancel / add product / edit product] go back to the table view, it no longer sorts.

I've tried adding the view child to see if I can renderrows after an add, but no dice.

**CODE:** https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-wez8lh

(Please excuse the horrendous CSS)

Is there a way to get it to sort again after [add / edit / cancel] without putting the form in another path or always showing it?

Comment: I managed all this by using ngrx-data for simplify all ngrx store-effect-entity and use a dialog for add-edit product, I can pass some simple code but you need to know ngrx for understand it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[**HERE IS A WORKING STACKBLITZ**](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unvzte?file=src/app/products/products.component.ts) 
The problem you have is the *ngIf in the mat-table selector. If you check this.sort you'll see it's undefined. This works :

```
@ViewChild(MatSort) set content(content: ElementRef) {
  this.sort = content;
  if (this.sort){
     this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

  }
}
```

Comment: This is great, thanks. It also works with the paginator!
`@ViewChild(MatPaginator) set pageContent (pageContent: ElementRef) {
    this.paginator = pageContent;
    if (this.paginator) this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
  }`

Comment: Thanks for providing the stackblitz example, it helped me figure this out. I had to make sure `dataSource` was initialized when it was declared (rather than in `ngOnInit`). Also, I changed `ElementRef` to `MatSort` in order to get rid of the `Type 'ElementRef<any>' is missing the following properties from type 'MatSort': sortables, _stateChanges, active, start, and 15 more` typescript error.

Comment: glad I helped!!