# Angular material table testing Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sortChange')

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular-test

In my component grid I've got this code:

```
 @ViewChild(MatSort) sort!: MatSort;
    ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.subscription.add(
      this.sort.sortChange.subscribe(() => (this.paginator.pageIndex = 0))
    );
    this.subscription.add(
      merge(this.sort.sortChange, this.paginator.page).subscribe((data) => {
        this.dataSource.paginator = this.paginator;
        this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;
      })
    );
  }
```

when I run the test suite I've this error:

> Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'sortChange')

I tried fix it with

```
component.sort = loader.getHarness(MatSortHarness);
```

The code above give me the error

> Type 'Promise' is missing the following properties
> from type 'MatSort': sortables, _stateChanges, active, start

How can I fix it?

I've tried also with

```
beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(AdminUsersGridComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    loader = TestbedHarnessEnvironment.loader(fixture);
    const data: UserResponseDto[] = [
      { id: 'oooo', email: '', role: 'user' as UserRoleDto, username: '' }
    ];
    console.log(loader);
    component.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource(data);
    component.sort = new MatSort();
    component.dataSource.sort = component.sort;
    fixture.detectChanges();
  });
```

with no luck :(

Comment: you can use this solution https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55975626/mat-table-not-sorting-after-view-change?answertab=active#tab-top

Comment: The problem is not in the code I use ngAfterViewInit and it works problem is in the test r may be I don't get the hint